# Would an aviation engineering background be helpful for a Flight Data Monitoring Analyst?

Tags: career

I am working now in the aviation sector and I am technical administrator for planning aircraft maintenance events. Recently I search for new opportunities and found "Flight Data Monitoring Analyst"? Could someone tell me should I have an aviation engineering background to qualify this job?

In their job description, candidates need to have bachelor degree and experience working in the aviation sector.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! It would be useful if you could post more information such as the actual job description. You could also just try applying to the jobs or messaging the company advertising them, the worst that will say is "go away" or just ignore you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to know if you specifically need an aviation **engineering** background rather than just **general** aviation background?

Comment: I wonder as a FDR analyst, should I know how to read the aircraft attitude, speed and height etc. I tried to google more info about Flight Data Monitoring but what I found it is mostly about Flight Data.

Comment: Today's aircraft record many parameters, some are even sent live to headquarters. Besides accident investigation, these data can be analyzed to identify patterns, trends etc for improvements in safety, efficiency, economy etc. It'd help if you already has an understanding of various aviation concepts, but I don't think aviation engineering or pilot experience is necessary (although it'd certainly help).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Skybrary's page on Flight Data Monitoring](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Flight_Data_Monitoring) defines Flight Data Analysis:

> **Flight Data Analysis** is founded on **Operational Flight Data Monitoring (OFDM)** which in North America has become known as **Flight Operations Quality Assurance (FOQA).** It is a process which routinely captures and analyses recorder data in order to improve the safety of flight operations.
>
> **Flight Data Analysis.** A process of analysing recorded flight data in order to improve the safety of flight operations. (ICAO Annex 6 - Operation of aircraft)
>
> **Operational Flight Data Monitoring (OFDM)** is the pro-active use of recorded flight data from routine operations to improve aviation safety.

So, this position would be focused on analyzing data from the flight data recorders to make sure the aircraft are being flown in safe and efficient manner.

Engineering (both in aviation and in general) is concerned with design. While an aviation engineering background would probably provide some useful insights, it normally isn't necessary for a position that is not concerned with designing aircraft or aircraft systems.

It would seem that piloting knowledge would be more necessary here than engineering knowledge. In order to analyze whether flight operations are being conducted safely and efficiently, you first need to know what constitutes safe and efficient flight. Technical knowledge of aircraft systems would certainly be needed, but probably more on a pilot level than an engineer level. Additionally, statistical analysis experience will almost certainly be needed.

As an example, here are the qualifications listed for [a Flight Data Management Analyst position](http://www.aviationjobsearch.com/job/flight-surveillance-analyst-1/4157933) that I found in a search:

> **Essential skills and qualifications**:
>
> - Experience in statistical analysis and preparation of graphical representation of data
> - Hold accreditation as an aircraft accident/incident investigator or equivalent
> - Hold accreditation as quality auditor or equivalent
>
> **Desirable skills and qualifications**:
>
> - Experience as a pilot
> - Sound aviation technical knowledge in Flying Operations, or equivalent
>     Experience in analysis of flight data, using flight data analysis systems (e.g. ADI, Aerobytes, AirFase)
> - Experience in utilisation of flight simulator software to recreate flight events
> - Familiarity with current EASA regulatory legislation
> - Experience in undertaking investigations